# \DeclareMathOperator not working on some math names with a number at the end

Tags: math-operators

I am trying to use `\DeclareMathOperator` to make names for some Maple generated latex which uses the special function [LommelS1](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=LommelS1)

For some reason I can't figure out, it is not working.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\LommelS1}{LommelS1}
\DeclareMathOperator{\LommelS2}{LommelS2}

\begin{document}
\[
\LommelS1 x
\]
\end{document}
```

Error is

```
>lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2018)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
! Use of \LommelS doesn't match its definition.
l.14 \LommelS1
             x
?
```

Notice it is looking for `\LommelS` but the operator is `\LommelS1`

It seems the number at the end of the operator is confusing it. Also when I remove the second `\DeclareMathOperator` now it works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\LommelS1}{LommelS1}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\LommelS2}{LommelS2}  %when commented, it works
\begin{document}
\[
\LommelS1 x
\]
\end{document}
```

But I need to use `\LommelS1` and `\LommelS2` so the numbers at the end are important since Maple latex will contain both such names.

Is where a way around this?

TL 2018

Comment: Command names cannot have digits in them, only letters.

Comment: `\newcommand{\LommelS}[1]{\operatorname{LommelS#1}}` will do if `\LommelS` is always followed by `1` or `2` (or a single digit). A slower routine is needed otherwise. Without more information it's not possible to say more.

Comment: @egreg thanks. Yes, the commands from Maple only have 1 or 2 at the end. So I will try your suggestion above now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's no `\LommelS` without a following digit and Maple always generates either `\LommelS1` or `\LommelS2`, then it's easy:

```
\newcommand{\LommelS}[1]{\operatorname{LommelS#1}}
```

You should know that only letters are accepted in command names that have a letter in their name (only a single nonletter can form a command name).